# Regex that considers apostrophes as word characters?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-2.1

I want to split a string on non-word characters (`\W`) *except* apostrophes. I want apostrophes to count as normal word characters.

Is there a way I can specify this simply?

Comment: It depends on the language you are using.

Comment: There shouldn't be all that many variations.  It's not like it's a complicated regex.

Comment: @stribizhev Oops, I forgot to include that in my post. I'm using Ruby 2.

Comment: I thought about character class subtractions.... like `[\W&&[^']]`....